# Getting the width or maximum distance of multilinestrings

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have several multiline strings. Each string consists of 2 to 8 almost parallel lines. I now want to have the largest distance between the two outer lines or calculate the maximum width of my multiline strings.

So I'm looking for something like this:
`ST_Width(ST_Boundary(ST_GeomFromEWKT(geometry)))`

I have a few question about this:

- How are length and width of a boundary defined?
- Is this dependent on the position in the room?
- Is the larger value automatically the length and the smaller value the width?

In my case all lines are about the same length. However, the length of a line can be shorter than the distance between the innermost and outermost line (case 2).
The orientation in my room can also be different (case 3).

Therefore the following sketch illustrates my problem (in red the value I want to calculate):

[image: width of multilinestrings]

---

I'm overthinking my strategy. The lines of the multi line strings are ordered (ID 0 to 8). For each set of multilines I try to use st_distance between the line with lowest and highest ID. Hopefully, it will work.

Otherwise, I try ST_ConvexHull. It seems a good way to solve my problem, too.

Comment: could you check if the outer lines happen to always correspond to the first and last geometry of each multiline?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's actually a really complicated problem.

What I would do is first dump the geometries and then try to select the 2 extreme lines then simply use st_distance.

To select the 2 extreme, if they are ordered it's easy but if they are not, if you are sure they have the same length try `order by ST_XMin, ST_YMin` and take the first and the last one.

Also: I don't think `ST_Boundary` works (I'm not sure how it handle multigeometry) because it usually descend one level (the boundary of a line is 2 points, the boundary of a polygon is a line). `ST_Envelope` would not work either, because it's an oriented polygon (NSEW). And `ST_Width` is for raster.

`ST_ConvexHull` can be a lead too: if you get the polygon around your lines, you have the `ST_Area`, if if your lines are all the same length you can deduct the width using the formula of a rectangle area (of course it works only if your lines are all the same length inside your multigeometry).